# Refinement of Notion of Integration

Tags: integration

I was trying to think of integration from the ground up and ran into a problem. The most naive way of thinking about integral of a function is just the sum of its values at all points in the domain over which it is integrated.
But the immediate problem is that for a dense set and a function whose value is finite over the set, the integral diverges.

So my question is how should we proceed in our definition of integration, and why does the new approach (whatever it is) gives us "the sum of the values at all points" satisfactorily?

Comment: It is not correct to think the integral as the "sum of all the values" of a function.

Comment: You forgot to scale by the width of the interval: you're integrating $f(x) dx$, not $f(x)$. Or alternatively, think of adding up all the (signed) rectangular areas.

Comment: Incidentally, in measure theory, there exists measures such that the integral $\int f d\mu$ really is the weighted sum of the values of $f$ at countably many points.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini : I don't dispute your statement, but why is it not correct to think of it in that way?

Comment: @ul15524 You *can* view an integral as a kind of uncountable sum of function values - as Hurkyl points out, for some kinds of measure it even is a sum in the tranditional sense. But for the measures where it's not, that view doesn't really help - the usual way that summation is defined for infinite but countably many summands doesn't extend to uncountably many summands easily...

Comment: Because it results in a "theory of integration" that's essentially useless (it only converges when there are countably many nonzero values, and even then not always). It's just a summation in disguise.

Comment: Well it simply doesn't include the size of the base of those little 'Towers' one draws usually. What you consider is therefore merely summation what is very good understood as the net of finite sums. Funnily this coincides with the integral for the counting measure (in mos cases). Try to have a look in the preface of the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788301/banach-space-valued-integration-riemann-type If u want to work on that you can address me - I myself think into the same direction as you do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is not representing the sum of the values of the function (that is called *sum* or *summation* like in $\sum f(x)$).

The integral might be thought as the sum of the values of the function, each one weighted with the *measure* of the domain where the function has such a value. This can be represented as a sum if the function has only a finite number of values i.e. if $f$ is what is called, a *simple function*:
$$
\int_\Omega f = \sum_{y\in f(\Omega)} y \cdot\mathrm{meas}\left(\Omega \cap f^{-1}(\{y\})\right). 
$$

In the general case one should approximate the function $f$ with simple functions from above and from below, and consider the extremal values of the integrals of simple functions.