# Reinventing The Wheel - Part 1: The Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

**Preface**

The core of any notion of integral is some sort of weighted sum:
$$\sum b\mu(A)$$

Depending on wether the domain or range is decomposed these split into Riemann and Lebesgue type ones:
$$\{A_i\}_{I \in I}: b_i\in fA_i$$
$$\{b_i\}_{I \in I}:A_i=f^{-1}\{b_i\}$$

In order to handle kinds of infinite sums one can introduce a notion of convergence:
$$\lim_{\leq}$$
The crucial ingredient for uniqueness is a directed order together with a Hausdorff space:
$$\leq\text{ directed}\\
\mathcal{T}\text{ Hausdorff}$$
(For more details see [Hausdorffness vs Uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821702/topology-hausdorff-leftrightarrow-unique-limits).)

*(Besides, these two first facts, namely summation and convergence, are the ones that weak notions of integral exploit.)*

For Lebesgue type ones the natural notion of convergence fails; that is plain summation gives:
$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=x:\quad\{\sum_{b\in B}b\mu(f^{-1}\{b\})\}_{\# B_0<\infty}=0\qquad B_0\leq B_0':\iff B_0\subseteq B_0'$$
For Riemann type ones this subtlety does not arise since it foots on collections of sets rather than elements. That will be the starting point of this article!

**Strategy & Goal**

The basic strategy of this article is to study a notion of integral of Riemann type under a suitable notion of convergence with:

- Hausdorff topological vector space: $V$
- Measure space of possible infinite size: $\mu(\Omega)\leq\infty$
- Integral of Riemann type: $I(f)=\lim_{\leq}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}f(b)\mu(A)$

The primary goal will be to entail functions with poles and oscillations while retaining uniformly continuous functionsof the following form:

- Uniformly continuous: $I(f)\text{ exists}$
- Poles: $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}: f(x):=x^{\alpha>-1}$
- Oscillation: $g:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}: g(x):=\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)$

**Definition**

Consider a sigma-finite complete measure space and a Banach space as well as Banach space valued functions:
$$(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)\text{ and }(E,\|\cdot\|) \text{ and }(\mathcal{F},\ldots)$$

Define the integral if it exists by:
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_{(\Sigma_0,\leq)}\left\{\sum_{(A,a)\in\Sigma_0}\mu(A)f(a)\right\}_{\Sigma_0}$$
with the finite collections of disjoint measurable subsets of finite size:
$$\Sigma_0\subseteq\Sigma: \qquad \#\Sigma_0<\infty\text{ as well as }\mu(A)<\infty\text{ and }A\cap B=\varnothing\text{ for }A\neq B,A,B\in\Sigma_0$$
being ordered by refinement and expansion:
$$\Sigma_0\leq\Sigma_0':\iff\Sigma_0\dashv\Sigma_0',\Sigma_0\prec\Sigma_0'$$
where refinement and expansion are defined as: $$\Sigma_0\dashv\Sigma_0':\iff\forall A\in\Sigma_0\exists A'\in\Sigma_0':A\supseteq A'$$
$$\Sigma_0\prec\Sigma_0':\iff\cup_{A\in\Sigma_0}A\subseteq\cup_{A'\in\Sigma_0'}A'$$

In fact, these are considered as tagged collections but for better reading this is masked: $(A,a)\in\Sigma_0$
Note also that the collections are not required to actually cover the measure space: $\cup_{A\in\Sigma_0}A\subseteq\Omega$
The ordering of collections is chosen so to give the right result: $\int s\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{e\in \mathrm{im}s}\mu(s^{-1}\{e\})e$

**Interpretation:**

This can be interpreted as *the* *net* of simple functions:
$$s_{\Sigma_0}:=\sum_{(A,a)\in\Sigma_0}f(a)\chi_A$$

Then the above read:
$$\int s_{\Sigma_0}\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Moreover for integrable functions the net of simple functions converges pointwise (proof?):
$$\left(\int s_{\Sigma_0}\mathrm{d}\mu \to \int f\mathrm{d}\mu\right) \Rightarrow \left(s_{\Sigma_0}(\omega)\to f(\omega)\right)$$
(Note that it is claimed pointwise convergence *everywhere* rather than almost everywhere.)

So the question arises how this Riemann type integral relates to the Lebesgue type integral by Bochner.
(The crucial difference is that this approach considers *the* *net* of simple functions related to the function under consideration while the approach by Bochner considers *some* *sequence* of simple functions not necessarily related to the function under consideration.)

**Discussion:**

It turns out that this notion of integrability is very restrictive.

A necessary condition on integrability is:
$$\exists\mu(N)=0: \|f(\Omega\setminus N)\|<\infty$$

So though the first critical example won't be dissolved by this notion:
$$f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
the second will be dissolved however:
$$g:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)$$

Especially no Lebesgue type integrability does imply this Riemann type integrability.

However, a positive result is achieved on finite measure spaces.

A sufficient condition on integrability is:
$$\ldots$$

Absolute integrability does not imply integrability (example?).

Regarding convergence theorems the uniform convergence theorem holds (proof?) but the dominated, monotone and Fatou convergence theorem fail (example?).

**Summary:**

$$\ldots$$

Comment: It would make more sense if you write ‘$ \displaystyle I(s) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sum_{e \in E} \mu({s^{-1}}[\{ e \}]) \cdot e $’.

Comment: If you wish to develop Banach space-valued integration theory, you might want to use *strongly measurable functions* instead of just measurable functions in the sense of Rudin. This is because a Banach space may not be separable.

Comment: Isn't that precisely the Bochner integral? If so I will add this to the question of this thread to the approach via simple function as a third strategy...

Comment: As to your correction: I want to keep it as simple as possible whenever it is clear from the context - I hope u don't mind...

Comment: "Banach space valued functions" - wait, are you saying that the function's value is a Banach space, or the function's value is an element of a Banach space, or something else?

Comment: The values are elements of the Banach space (that is sloppy terminology usually used)

Comment: I don't want to be raining on your parade, but this seems more like something you should be posting on a blog. I don't see any question or whatever, just some exposition.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Yeah I know - it started as a question and become a dead end as it failed at a critical point. Will vote to close it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the ordering gives:
$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=x:\quad\text{ not integrable}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt:**

Assume every point admits a subset of finite measure (sigma-finite measure spaces do so) that is every point comes into consideration eventually: $\forall\omega\in\Omega\exists\Sigma_0: \omega\in A\in\Sigma_0$

Fix the point and consider two cases.

All measurable subsets containing the point are of bounded size: $\mu(A_{\omega})\geq C>0$
Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=C\epsilon$. Find $\Sigma_\delta$. Assume w.l.o.g. $\omega\in A\in\Sigma_\delta$. Regard $\Sigma_a\geq\Sigma_\delta$. Retag $\Sigma_\omega=\Sigma_a$.
So it follows:
$$\|f(a)-f(\omega)\|<\frac{\delta}{\mu(A_\omega)}\leq\frac{C\epsilon}{C}=\epsilon$$

Some measurable subsets containing the point tend to zero size: $\mu(A_n)\to 0$
Since the intersection has zero measure the singleton is measurable by completeness with finite size: $\mu(\omega)<\infty$
Thus it holds:
$$s_{\Sigma_0}(\omega)=f(\omega)\text{ for all }\Sigma_0\geq\{(\{\omega\},\omega)\}$$