# Banach Space: Open Unit Ball Totally Bounded?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Just to be sure: In an infinite dimensional Banach space the open unit ball cannot be totally bounded, right? The context is that I need this in order to find a lack in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886597/reinventing-the-wheel-part-2-the-lebesgue-integral)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the open unit ball were totally bounded, then so would its closure, which is the closed unit ball. The closed unit ball, in turn, is complete (as a closed subset of a Banach space). Hence, the closed unit ball would be compact, which it can be shown it is not, given that the space is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: I doubt that you can carry over arguments of totally boundedness on closures without additional arguments...

Comment: @Freeze_S Let $E$ be a totally bounded subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^N\subseteq X$ and $N\in\mathbb N$ be such that $E\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^N B(\varepsilon/2,x_j)$, which is possible by the definition of total boundedness. It is not difficult to see that $\overline E\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^N B(\varepsilon,x_j)$. This shows that if $E$ is totally bounded, then so is $\overline E$.

Comment: Your 'it is not difficult to see that' is wrong (take $E=B(\epsilon,x_0)$ itself).

Comment: @Freeze_S If $E=B(\varepsilon,x_0)$ and $x\in\overline E$, then there exists some $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$ (by the definition of closure). Since $y\in E$, it follows that $d(y,x_0)<\varepsilon$. By the triangle inequality, $d(x,x_0)<2\varepsilon$. Conclusion: $\overline E\subseteq B(2\varepsilon,x_0)$. I don't really see what's the glitch here.

Comment: Ah I missed the $\frac12$ that makes sense of course - thx ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S My pleasure, I'm glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You are right: it is not totally bounded. [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma) directly leads to an infinite uniformly separated subset of unit ball, as the Wikipedia article shows.

Comment: But don't we have to be careful about the *open* ball? Sure, the closed ball is not totally bounded but subsets of it (as the open ball) still can be...

Comment: @Freeze_S Sure, the open ball of radius $1$ contains closed ball of radius $1/2$.